# Unable to compile arm assembly file with armasm

Tags: assembly, arm, pocketpc, mpeg

I'm using libmpeg2 for showing video in my pocket pc project. Last release of this lib has acceleration for ARM processor,  some of the functions are rewritten in arm assembly (in separate file motion_comp_arm_s.S).
The problem is armasm from Visual Studio 9 cant compile it, producing a lot of errors. My question is, which arm assembly compiler is suitable for such code?

```
    .text
```

@ ----------------------------------------------------------------
    .align
    .global MC_put_o_16_arm
MC_put_o_16_arm:
    @@ void func(uint8_t * dest, const uint8_t * ref, int stride, int height)
    pld [r1]
        stmfd sp!, {r4-r11, lr} @ R14 is also called LR
    and r4, r1, #3
    adr r5, MC_put_o_16_arm_align_jt
    add r5, r5, r4, lsl #2
    ldr pc, [r5]
   
...

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the syntax used by the [GNU assembler](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/index.html). The code itself should be (more or less) the same for any assembler; to make this build with the microsoft assembler, the main changes will be:

- Change the `@` characters (which denote comments) to `;`
- Change the directives (the words beginning with `.`) documented [here](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Pseudo-Ops.html#Pseudo-Ops) to their Microsoft equivalents, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253551%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). For example `.text` becomes `CODE`.

This should fix most of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use ARM RVDS compiler
Syntax of a sample code goes like this

```
      AREA     ARMex, CODE, READONLY
      ENTRY
START
      MOV R0,#1
      MOV R1,#2
      ADD R0,R0,R1
      END
```

Save the code as test.s
command to compile and generate object file is

```
armasm --arm test -o test.s
```